# Configuring APC Caching

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, ubuntu, apc

I am in the middle of migrating 7 Wordpress sites to one single server which is running Ubuntu and has 4 core CPUs & 15gb ram)

So far I have moved one website and installed APC, but I am unsure if this method of caching supports multiple websites on one server.

Can anyone give me some advice on configuration? Can I just install it and use it 'Out of the box' or do I need to make some tweaks that will increase performance for all 7 websites.

It looks like it currently only uses 30mb ram which doesnt seem like a lot to me.

Cheers,

Rich

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use some apc cache plugin, the most common one in use is http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/.

It's easy to set up and provides a lot more.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What do you mean by: 'provides a lot more'? Do you know if I can use APC with multiple websites?

Answer (score 0):

W3 Total Cache would be a good choice, and it would pose no problems for APC. For a basic install it is sufficient to just configure the main configuration page.

Typically you would set the options there as follows:

- page cache: enable, disk enhanced
- minify: disable (you could experiment with this, but maybe causes errors on your site. If you try it, set it to disk)
- database cache: enable, apc
- object cache: enable, apc
- browser cache: enable
- CDN: disable
- Varnish: disable

Of course there are a lot of other options, with which you can experiment a little to suit your needs. But these settings should give you a solid performance boost.

I would also take a look at the settings in your apc.ini. By default, the amount of memory allocated for the service is not very large. Maybe increase that to 512mb or 1024mb.